# Get Yandex domain email with api

Tags: yandex, yandex-api

I have try create an application for my team get email from yandex domain. I have success create email but I can't read the email from my mailbox. On the document don't mention this feature but I think this exits. The link can get number of email on mailbox but I don't find how to read the email.
https://tech.yandex.com/domain/doc/reference/email-counters-docpage/

The question is: How to read the email on the mailbox in Yandex mailbox via API.
Thanks for help me resolve this problem.

Comment: I think you could use imap to do this.

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your suggest. I'm using imap class and it's okay.